# Why is it that $\partial S^2=\emptyset$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

While doing some differential geometry I came across the following application of the Stokes Theorem. $$\int_{S^2}d(xdy)=\int_{\partial S^2}xdy$$
Now, the professor baldly affirms that $\partial S^2=\emptyset$. I don't understand why is that. Isn't it that $$\partial S^2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$$

Comment: We’re not talking about the topological boundary considered as a subset of the ambient $\Bbb{R}^3$. We’re talking about boundary in the manifold sense. The sphere is a smooth manifold without boundary in the manifold sense. See [Boundary of unit sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1743158/568204) (and the link within) for more details clarifying the double usage of the term “boundary”.

Comment: Hint: Stokes' theorem on an interval is the fundamental theorem of calculus $\int_{[a,b]}df =f(b)-f(a)\,.$ The relevant boundary of the interval consists of the points $a$ and $b\,.$

Comment: @peek-a-boo That should be an answer.